# Collect() from table in SQLite in R

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, rsqlite, dbplyr

I am trying to use the `collect()` function from `dplyr` to query a table (`comp_fleet`) in SQLite. The following code works:

```
Cposns <- tbl(db_con,"comp_fleet") %>% 
  arrange(mmsi, desc(timestamp))%>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(lat)) %>% collect()
```

However when I try `top_n()`, I get an error:

```
Cposns <- tbl(db_con,"comp_fleet") %>% 
  arrange(mmsi, desc(timestamp))%>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(lat)) %>% 
  top_n(1,timestamp) %>% collect()

Error: Window function `rank()` is not supported by this database
```

Since this is a huge table, I was hoping to carry out all aggregation functions within the database before collecting. Is there some way of using the `top_n()` function prior to `collect()`? Or something equivalent to it?

Comment: Have you tried to use `head()` instead of `top_n()`?. Your dataframe is not grouped, so you probably don't need `top_n()`.

Comment: @Scarabee thanks for your comment, just realized that I did need a `group_by()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Scarabee, this is what works:

```
Cposns <- tbl(db_con,"comp_fleet") %>%
  arrange(mmsi, desc(timestamp))%>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(lat)) %>% group_by(mmsi) %>%
  do(head(., n = 1)) %>% collect()
```